# XSLT: multiple tables

Tags: xslt

I come across this small problem while creating a xslt file... I have this generic xml file:

```
<data>
  <folder>
    <file>
      <name>file1</name>
      <date>2000</date>
      <index1>1</index1>
      <index2>1</index2>
    </file>

    <file>
      <name>file2</name>
      <date>2001</date>
      <index1>1</index1>
      <index2>1</index2>
    </file>

    <file>
      <name>file3</name>
      <date>2004</date>
      <index1>2</index1>
      <index2>1</index2>
    </file>
  </folder>
</data>
```

Given this abstract example, I have to transform it into something like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Date</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>file1</td>
    <td>2000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>file2</td>
    <td>2001</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Date</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>file3</td>
    <td>2004</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have to group the file elements per table based on their index1 and index2 (like an ID pair). I am able to create a table for every separated file, but I can't come with a solution to create a table for every file sharing index1 and index2. Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Are you stuck with XSLT 1.0 or are you using 2.0? There are solutions with both but they're rather simpler with XSLT 2.

Comment: I am using XSLT 2.0 .

Comment: Your life has become easier then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using XSLT 2.0 you can use the `xsl:for-each-group` statement. You have two choices here, depending on whether you wish to keep groups together and respect the sequence or whether you just want to group regardless of sequence.

That is, given `aabaab` would you want groups of `(aaaa, bb)` or `(aa, b, aa, b)`?

This first groups all file elements with the same `index1` and `index2` regardless of order in the document (I've put in the `body` element just to make it well-formed)

```
<xsl:template match="folder">
    <body>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="file" group-by="concat(index1, '-', index2)">
        <!-- xsl:for-each-group sets the first element in the group as the context node -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
    </body>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="file">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Date</td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="to-row"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="file" mode="to-row">
    <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="name|date"/>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name|date">
    <td><xsl:apply-templates/></td>
</xsl:template>
```

The second version would only need the first template changed to:

```
<xsl:template match="folder">
    <body>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="file" group-adjacent="concat(index1, '-', index2)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
    </body>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It makes a lot of sense! 
I am wondering how would the same issue looked like in 1.0.

Comment: @theTech In XSLT 1.0, that would be with the Muenchian Method. There are a bunch of questions on SO that cover that if you are curious. XSLT 2.0 makes this much easier.

Comment: @MatthewGreen I took a look on that method. Good to know they have improved this issue on version 2.0!

Comment: The Muenchian method works very well but it *is* rather complex.